# How to save a string in sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have an application where I need to save a string in a sharedpreferences so that the user has already opened the application once and registered his email he does not have to go through the same screen again and instead go to the home screen directly.

**My Class PreferencesHelpers**

```
public class PreferencesHelpers {

private static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
private static final String TEXT = "ahhsaushhuuashu"; //I want to save this string

public String text;


public static void saveData(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("", TEXT);

}

public static String loadData(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String text = sharedPreferences.getString("ahhsaushhuuashu", "");
    return text;
   }

}
```

**MyLogic in MainActivity to save and retrieve sharedPreferences value**

```
  if (!preferencesHelpers.loadData(getApplicationContext()).contains("ahhsaushhuuashu")) {
                webView.loadUrl(URL_);
                preferencesHelpers.saveData(getApplicationContext());
            } else {
                switch (urlMessage) {
                    case "REDR":
                        webView.loadUrl(URL + "cira");
                        break;
                    default:
                        webView.loadUrl(URL + "?UDI=" + getInstance().getRegistrationManager().getSystemToken() + "&dev=" + getInstance().getRegistrationManager().getDeviceId() + "&source=app");
                }
            }
```

I looked for an answer that fit my condition but I did not find and forgive me for my English

Comment: Why are you not assigning a key to your value in shared preferences? ```editor.putString("", TEXT);```

Comment: SharedPreference uses Key, value Pair. replace  editor.putString("", TEXT); with editor.putString("savingKey", TEXT); And     String text = sharedPreferences.getString("ahhsaushhuuashu", "");
with     String text = sharedPreferences.getString("savingKey", "");. this should work fine

Comment: Above answers + you missed `apply()`, when you want to save your preference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a fixed key to save and read your preference and you forgot to apply the modifications of the SharedPreference.

You need to do like this:

```
private static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
private static final String TEXT = "ahhsaushhuuashu";
private static final String KEY = "myKey";

public static void saveData(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(KEY, TEXT);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String loadData(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String text = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY, "");
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others in the comments you need Keys for storing a value, but also I see that you are not saving the value in the **saveData** method.

You need to type in this line:

```
editor.apply()
```

after

```
editor.putString("", TEXT);
```

in the **saveData** method